# How to get the quarter corresponding to a date in Oracle SQL 19c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I think there was a function **extract(quarter from *date*)** in oracle sql to fetch the quarter for a given date. However the Oracle SQL 19c documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html#GUID-36E52BF8-945D-437D-9A3C-6860CABD210E) does not show the presence of `quarter` anymore.

I even tried running the code -

```
select extract(quarter from to_date('15/09/2021','DD/MM/YYYY')) as Q from dual;
```

The expected result is -

```
+---+
|  Q|
+---+
|  3|
+---+
```

Instead it gives an error

```
ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis
```

though it runs fine when `quarter` is replaced by `month` or `year`. What is the current way to fetch `quarter` given a date in Oracle SQL 19c?

Comment: I doubt that "quarter" ever was an option for `extract`. Even though in principle there is no reason not to have it, I believe `extract` is based strictly on the internal data format Oracle uses for dates. That format has separate bytes for year, month, day, etc. - but not for quarter, or for week, or other calendar units. Those are all calculated, and are not options to `extract`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will use `sysdate` for illustration - you can replace that with any expression of `date` data type.

The query returns a string (of a single character, a digit between 1 and 4); if you need a `number` value, wrap it within `to_number()`.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'Q') as qtr from  dual;

QTR
---
3
```